# Refill form after submit

Tags: php, xslt, transform

I use XSLT as template engine in my PHP framework. HTML forms are in XML files and XSLT transforms it to HTML.

**How to refill forms after submit?**

Now framework converts all $_POST and $_GET into xml and pass to XSLTProcessor. XSLT template puts that information into correct HTML input elements.

**Is it save to do it like this? Maybe there is a better way to do this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the framework uses htmlentities() to make sure you can't add xml elements before it goes to the XSLTProcessor then you're fine.

The security assumptions here are: you control the server output, but user input is never to be trusted.